# Calculadora de 3 archivos C++ Como hago para juntar los 3 archivos en uno?

Tags: c++

Calculadora de 3 archivos C++ Como hago para juntar los 3 archivos en uno?
Tengo el fichero main.cpp, calculadora.cpp y calculadora.h pero quiero juntarlos en un solo
Que tendría que hacer para juntar los 3 archivos en uno?

```
#include<iostream>
#include "windows.h"

#include "Calculadora.h"
using namespace std;
int main () {
    int opcion=0;
    int inv;
    float a=0;
    float b=0;
    int n, nDivisible, nEvaluar, con5, con0, cantDigitosUno, cantDigitosDos;
    
    Calculadora c;
    system("color 5f");
    cout<<"===============================================================\n";
    cout<<"                         MENU                                  \n";
    cout<<"===============================================================\n";
    cout<<"1. SUMA"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. RESTA"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. MULTIPLICACION"<<endl;
    cout<<"4. DIVISION"<<endl;
    cout<<"5. RAIZ CUADRADA"<<endl;
    cout<<"6. POTENCIA"<<endl;
    cout<<"7. DIGITOS MAYORES QUE 5 E IGUALES A 0"<<endl;
    cout<<"8. INVERSA DE NUMERO"<<endl;
    cout<<"9. NUMEROS IGUALES"<<endl;
    cout<<"10. SALIR"<<endl;
    cout<<"===============================================================\n\n";
    cout<<"=============================================================\n\n\n";
    cout<<"Digite la opcion que desea (1 a 10): ";
    cin>>opcion;
    system ("cls");
    if(opcion==1){
        cout<<"##################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"#  BIENVENIDO A LA SECCION SUMA  #"<<endl;
        cout<<"##################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"Digite el primer numero"<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"Digite el segundo numero"<<endl;
        cin>>b;
        cout<<"El resultado es: "<<c.Suma(a,b);
    }
    else if(opcion==2){
        cout<<"############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"#      BIENVENIDO A LA SECCION RESTA       #"<<endl;
        cout<<"############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"Digite el primer numero"<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"Digite el segundo numero"<<endl;
        cin>>b;
        cout<<"El resultado es: "<<c.Resta(a,b);
    }
    else if(opcion==3){
        cout<<"############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"#  BIENVENIDO A LA SECCION MULTIPLICACION  #"<<endl;
        cout<<"############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"Digite el primer numero"<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"Digite el segundo numero"<<endl;
        cin>>b;
        cout<<"El resultado es: "<<c.Multiplicacion(a,b);
    }
    else if(opcion==4){
        cout<<"############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"#  BIENVENIDO A LA SECCION DIVISION  #"<<endl;
        cout<<"############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"Digite el primer numero"<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"Digite el segundo numero"<<endl;
        cin>>b;
        cout<<"El resultado es: "<<c.Division(a,b);
    }
    else if(opcion==5){
        cout<<"############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"#  BIENVENIDO A LA SECCION RAIZ CUADRADA   #"<<endl;
        cout<<"############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"Digite un numero"<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"El resultado es: "<<c.Raiz(a);
    }
    else if(opcion==6){
        cout<<"############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"#     BIENVENIDO A LA SECCION POTENCIA     #"<<endl;
        cout<<"############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"Digite el primer numero"<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"Digite el segundo numero"<<endl;
        cin>>b;
        cout<<"El resultado es: "<<c.Potencia(a,b);
    }
    else if(opcion==7){
        cout<<"#############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"#  BIENVENIDO A LA SECCION DIGITOS MAYORES  #"<<endl;
        cout<<"#############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"Introduce un numero: ";cin>>n;
        nDivisible=n;
        while(n){
            nEvaluar = n%10;
            if(nEvaluar>5){
                con5++;
            }else if(nEvaluar==0){
                con0++;
            }
            n /= 10;
        }
        cout<<"La cantidad de  digitos mayores de 5 que tiene el numero: "<<nDivisible<<" es de: "<<con5<<" y la cantidad de digitos iguales a cero es de: "<<con0<<endl<<endl;system ("pause");system("cls");  
    }
    else if(opcion==8){
        cout<<"###############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"#  BIENVENIDO A LA SECCION INVERSA DE NUMERO  #"<<endl;
        cout<<"###############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"Digite un numero que desee invertir: ";
        cin>>n;
        int inv2=0;
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
            inv2= (n%10)+inv2*10;
            n = n/10;
        }
        cout<<"El numero invertido es: "<<c.inv(inv2);
        
    }
    else if(opcion==9){
        cout<<"#############################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"#  BIENVENIDO A LA SECCION NUMEROS IGUALES  #"<<endl;
        cout<<"#############################################"<<endl;
        do{
            cout<<"Por favor digite un numero"<<endl;cin>>a;
            cout<<"Por favor digite el otro numero"<<endl;cin>>b;
            if(a==0 ||  b==0){
                cout<<"Ambos numeros deben ser diferentes de 0"<<endl;
            }
        }while(a==0 || b==0);
        cantDigitosUno = log10 (a)+1;
        cantDigitosDos = log10 (b)+1;
        if(a==b){
            cout<<"El numero "<< a<<" tiene "<<cantDigitosUno<<" digitos"<<" Y el numero "<<b<<" tiene "<<cantDigitosDos<<" digitos "<<"numeros son iguales"<<endl<<endl;system ("pause");system("cls");
        }else{
        cout<<"El numero "<<a<<" tiene "<<cantDigitosUno<<" digitos"<<" Y el numero "<<b<<" tiene "<<cantDigitosDos<<" digitos"<<" los numeros son diferentes "<<endl<<endl;system ("pause");system("cls");
    }   
    }else if(opcion==10){
        cout<<"ADIOS,GRACIAS POR SU USO"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Error, opcion no disponible"<<endl;
        
    }
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Porqué querrías hacer eso? Lo ideal es tenerlo separados, tienes tú código y la librería (header y contenido).

Answer (score 0):

No sé porqué querrías hacer eso, me parece que solo va a hacer que tu código sea más difícil de leer y mantener... Peeerooooo, si realmente lo necesitas en un archivo, te comento que lo que hace `#include` es simplemente copiar los contenidos de tu archivo en ese lugar del código (eso es lo que hace tu compilador).

Entonces lo que tendrías que hacer por ejemplo es que en dónde diga `#include "Calculadora.h"` solo copia todo el código que habita en ese archivo `"Calculadora.h"`.

Si realmente no existe un motivo por el cual **necesites** hacer el archivo uno solo, entonces considero hacer esto un mala práctica.

Comment: Mi profesor dice que si no lo hago como el nos explica y si hacemos cosas que no nos enseña nos pondrá malo, por eso, si no no lo haría obviamente

Comment: Oh, entiendo tu caso, no me parece en lo más mínimo una buena recomendación, pero bueno... ¡Ve por esa buena nota entonces! Solo copia el código dónde haces los includes.

Comment: Si exacto, a mi tampoco me parece ya que así como lo tengo esta buenísimo pero toca.

Comment: Como se haría? es que intente hacer en uno diferente uniendo los 3 archivos pero me tiro errores por Calculadora.h

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de error?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/xcLqGot este error

Comment: Ok, sí ya veo que es lo que está pasando, creo que la solución que di requiere de un poco más de conocimiento. 1. Si ya copiaste el código no ocupas el include 2.No repitas include 3.No copies todo el archivo, solo copia la declaración de la clase del .h y  la definición de la misma del .cpp

Comment: Es que voy apenas en el primer semestre jaja soy muy nuevo en esto pero ahí voy aprendiendo

Comment: No te preocupes, vas bien, es complicado. Si alguien te dice que es fácil probablemente tenga amnesia raro de cuando inicio a programar o simplemente quiere presumir.

Comment: Creo que no me sirvió o no entendí bien